# If $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $v + A = \{v + x: x\in A \}$ an open set $\forall v \in \mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that if $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^n} \Rightarrow$ $\forall v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ : $v + A = \{v + x: x \in A \}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$

I know that a set $A$ is an open set if
$$
\forall x \in A, \exists \epsilon \gt 0 : B(x, \epsilon) \subset A
$$

The proof seems trivial but I dont know how to prove it.Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Are you just using the slash to separate the quantifiers from the predicate?

Comment: @BrianTung yes :)

Comment: Can you use the invertible map $x \mapsto x+v$ to go from an arbitrary point in $v+A$ to the corresponding point in $A$, and then from the neighborhood of that corresponding point to the neighborhood of the arbitrary point in $v+A$?  (ETA: You would use the inverse map in the first instance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set and define $v+A = \{v+x \, |  \, x \in A \}$ for a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We will show that $v+A$ is open. Let $x \in v + A$. Observe that $x-v \in A$, and that consequently there exits an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x-v, \epsilon) \subset A$. Now, its easy to see (and check if you want to) that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset v + A$.

The geometric idea here is that $v+A$ is simply a translation of the set $A$, so that if $B(x, \epsilon) \subset A$, the corresponding translated ball $B(x+v, \epsilon) \subset v+A$.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach. Let $s: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the sum function:
$$s(v,u) := v+u$$
It is easy to see that $s$ is continuous. Thus, for a fixed $v \in \mathbb{R}$, the associate function $s_{v}: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$s_{v}(u) := v+u$$
is not only continuous, but a homeomorphism (that is, it is a continuous bijection and its inverse is again continuous). Thus, if $A$ is an open set:
$$s_{v}(A) = v+A$$
must be open.